# Why am I missing elements in my array from array.from()

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml-parsing

I am currently building a large database from an imported XML document, about 13k items or so. When I do

```
window.onload = function() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            let text = reader.result;
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"application/xml");
            getReportList(xmlDoc);
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);    
    } else {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
    }
});
}

function isGroupTag(arr) {
return arr.nodeName === "Group";
}

function getReportList(xml) {
    // Creates an array containing all reports
    let reportList = Array.from(xmlDoc.children[0].children).filter(isGroupTag);
    allReports = reportList.map((currElement, index) => { 
        return getReport(xml, index);
    });
}
```

I only get back about 2100? I checked my program using a much smaller XML document and every thing was loaded fine. Any ideas as to why I would be getting such a small return back? 
My first thought was that the XML document wasn't loaded completely yet so when I did `Array.from()` it was building the array with what it had...not sure though. Any help would be great.

EDIT:

I just finished testing loading in a few more XML documents. Instead of one massive file I loaded in the yearly ones and everything shows up. Still not sure why I can't just do the massive one.

Comment: Because you are filtering them? It's not like your code does anything wrong, and it's unlikely there's a bug in the xml implementation. Try re-exporting them and then compare with an external tool which of the records are missing

Comment: @Bergi I made xmlDoc a global variable for testing and it has all the records loaded. When I view it in the console it loads a good chunk of them and then has me click to reveal the rest of them. When I do `let test = Array.from(xmlDoc)`  it still only has the 2100 ish results in the array.

Comment: I don't think anyone can reproduce your error without more code. What is `reader`? How is it getting called? What is `isGroupTag`? Note that you pass `xmlDoc` to `getReportList` as `xml`, then use `xmlDoc` in `Array.from`; you should use `xml`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I updated my code to include the isGroupTag function and changed xmlDoc to xml. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JustinGagnon So your problem is just the console not showing all the items? What does `console.log(test.length)` give?